# How do I control order/arrangement of certain columns in a resultset?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to control the sort order ourselves in a result set? So if I want to give it a custom order of appearance (instead of the ASC or DESC order), how can I go about doing it? I have read some answers on Stackoverflow which talk about using CASE statements in ORDER BY, but I do not understand how that works and how to make it work to get what I want.

[image]

In the above column for example, I want, say, Mitchell to be last, Carson to be first, Reiter to be fifth, etc.

Comment: What do you mean "by ourselves"? You control the sort order using ORDER BY. Could you give us an example please?

Comment: For example, if say a column has the following rows:


Apple
Orange
Banana
...

I want third to be first, second to be third, you know, just order it the way I want it to appear. Was wondering if that was possible.

Comment: Can you share e a sample unordered dataset and the expected output ?

Comment: Edited the question as well :)

Comment: If you aren't using alpha-numeric sorting, then you likely have to create your own ordering mechanism though a new column.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, I got it to appear like this by using this:

CASE WHEN LastName = 'Blythe' THEN '1' 
    WHEN LastName = 'Reiter' THEN '2'
      WHEN LastName = 'Vargas' THEN '3' 
      ELSE LastName END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new ordering table with sort order and link that to your original table. Then sort it by the sort order. 
Like this:

```
DECLARE @SortTable TABLE (LastName nvarchar(50), SortOrder int)

INSERT INTO @SortTable 
VALUES        ('Carson', 1)
            , ('Vargas', 2)
            , ('Ansman-Wolfe', 3)
            , ('Pak', 4)
            , ('Reiter', 5)
            , ('Varkey Chudukatil', 6)
            , ('Blythe', 7)
            , ('Mitchell', 8)

SELECT      YT.*
FROM        YourTable     AS YT
INNER JOIN  @SortTable    AS ST
    ON      ST.LastName   = YT.LastName
ORDER BY    ST.SortOrder
```

I used a table variable, but of course you can also use a normal table that you add in your database. Make sure you add all the possible values for lastname, otherwise you would miss out rows.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I controlled this inside of the report in SSRS since it was just a visual requirement for two or three records.

Comment: Nice, I am glad I could help you out.